# How can I run a Linux Distro on my mid 2017 MacBook Pro 13 Inch?

Tags: linux-mint, virtualbox, keyboard, touchpad

1) I tried making a persistent USB drive with Linux Mint and Ubuntu but when i boot into the usb, I cannot use my touchpad or my keyboard. I tried everything online and did everything i read from https://gist.github.com/roadrunner2/1289542a748d9a104e7baec6a92f9cd7 but nothing seemed to work. I used an external mouse and keyboard to do this. The persistence worked and it would boot but i couldnt use any of my hardware and I dont want to have to have to use an external mouse and keyboard everytime.

2) Additionally, i tried to make a Virtual Machine with VirtualBox but it lags too much. Its slightly manageable but nevertheless still annoying. For example my mouse pointer would hover over an application and click it but it would take a second to register that and theres a high latency while typing too. I tried giving the VM 4 Gb ram, 2 GB ram, 2 Processor cores... Nothing worked and it still lags too much. I even tried downloading an older version of Linux Mint xfce hoping it would be less processor intensive but it still was too slow.

Answer (score 0):

You should use bootcamp to have dual boot. The process is straightforward. With that said, you will not be able to use everything, there is a compatibility list for it somewhere which I can't find right now. This is another link which shows compatible devices
https://wiki.debian.org/MacBook#Devices_that_work

I suggest switching to Parallel or vmware instead. Virtual box is very inefficient.

Also I use docker for my needs which is usually compiling a program or other command line based activities. There are various Linux flavors available. You could load one, install what you need and commit another image which has everything. For me an ubuntu with All my tools needs 1GB or so.